# How the VM instance set up on gcloud contains the fast.ai tutorials already?

Tags: gcloud, fast-ai

I am just about to start the fast.ai course and have followed [the instruction](https://course.fast.ai/start_gcp.html) to set up the VM instance on Google Compute Cloud. Surprisingly I found that when I started the instance and opened `localhost:8080/tree`, there is already a folder called `tutorials` that contains the course materials already.

My question is: how is this done through the instructions given by fast.ai? I thought only a VM with essential deep learning libraries would be set up by specifying `--image-project=deeplearning-platform-release` and `--image-family="pytorch-latest-gpu"`.

Answer (score 2):

I found the answer on [a course forum thread](https://forums.fast.ai/t/platform-gcp/27375/23).

The reason that the `tutorials` folder is already there is because

> Google DL Image preinstalls them for you as demo.